# Google Colab tools to estimate energy consumption and carbon footprint of Colab use?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm a Colab Pro subscriber. It seems like the environmental impact of training big models is now getting increasingly more visible. I've been training BERT, etc. on various downstream tasks over the last summer and am now wondering what's been the environmental impact of my work.

Are there any Colab tools that will estimate how much electricity I've used (in Watt x hour) and how much CO2 I've emitted in the Colab data center when I run a specific notebook from start to completion?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are interested in the power consumption of the algorithms you execute using Google's backend systems. I came across this paper: Green Algorithms: Quantifying the Carbon Footprint of Computation by Loïc Lannelongue https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/advs.202100707 which measures the power consumption of google's backend system. I reckon google colab uses google's backend GPUs and TPUs. Here is their carbon tracker website as well (https://www.green-algorithms.org) . I hope this helps. If I am wrong, please let me know.